# Javascript form submit

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, post, submit

I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible without php or some other scripting language so I would be grateful for some advice.

We have a webserver which can only serve static HTML so we're a bit limited. We want to post e-mail sign up data from a form on this site using JavaScript off to a `dataHandler.php` script on another domain which will save it to a DB. When the customer clicks submit I don't want the page to navigate away to `dataHandler.php` though on the other domain I want it to refresh in some way (I don't know how) and say thanks for joining our e-mail list. An example of the code I am thinking about is below.

Any advice on how it might be achieved would be gratefully appreciated or any comments saying stop wasting your time would also be helpful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function validate() {
if (document.emailForm.email.value.length==0) {
alert("You forgot to enter your email address");
return false;
}    
if (document.emailForm.email.value.length>0) {
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
var address = document.emailForm.email.value;
if(reg.test(address) == false) {
    alert('Invalid email address');
    return false;
    }
}
document.emailForm.submit()
return true;
}
//-->
</script>

<form id="emailForm" name="emailForm" action="http://www.otherdomain.com/dataHandler.php" method="post">
    <input size="30" id="email" name="email" maxlength="200" />
    <input onclick="validate();" type="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at the jQuery form plugin (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) . it does exactly what your looking for and can be implemented with one line of code.